# How do I show that the given solutions to an ODE constitute all solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm really stuck with this exercise. I hope you can help me.

> Consider the following ODE: \begin{equation} \ddot{z}-2 i z=0,\end{equation}
>
> Show that the solution space to the ODE is given by: \begin{equation}L=\left\{a e^{t+i t}+b e^{-t-i t} \mid a, b \in \mathbb{C}\right\} . \end{equation}

---

It's easy to verify that every element in L solves the given ODE.
However, this doesn't mean that there couldn't exist another type of solution, which is not an element in L.
So in order to show that the solution space is equal to L, I should somehow show that every solution that exists, has to be on the form written in L.
But I honestly have no idea how to do that. Do you have a hint?

Comment: This is a linear ODE. Did you learn about them? What can you say about the set of all solutions to a linear ODE?

Comment: If you could prove the solutions to that equation form a vector space of dimension 2, then the conclusion follows from proving $\{e^{(1+i)t},e^{-(1+i)t}\}$ forms a basis of that vector space.

Comment: @Hal Thanks. I just looked through my book, the reason I don't know this yet, is because the tools are in a later chapter we haven't covered yet. My book hasn't covered anything about vector spaces yet, that is only something I know from Linear algebra.

Comment: @Bennie Thanks for your reply. I believe I can solve it now, by using a theorem from a later chapter, that says this type of ODE has the vector space of dimension 2 of solutions. Or else I would have to prove that the solution space for the ODE has order 2, on my own. But I hope that is beyond the scope of this exercise.